# What is this "patent pending" part?

Tags: part-identification, trains

I found this part in our LEGO collection, and I'm really curious what it might be, it looks old and says "Pat. pend" on the back. Do you know? Thanks!

[image: Back of the white part says "Pat. pend"]

[image: The front has an interesting angle]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a tie plate from the original 4.5V train system, specifically from a "switch point right":

[image]

http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=x879cx1#T=C